# LINQ VB.NET Check Date between Effective and End Date (End Date can be null)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ query VB.NET that I have to check if a Date is between the timespan --- Here is the twist the Effective Date is required, but the End Date can be nullable

I can have the same record but the dates cannot overlap

```
  .Where(Function(x) x.srvc_def_desc = txtSrvDefDesc.Text.Trim()) _
                      .Where(Function(x) txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate >= x.eff_dt And (txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate <= x.end_dt)).Count()
```

The problem I am having is how to I check for a nullable date to count as a date being between the Effective and a End Date that does not expire?

Comment: Trying something like --- the following but not working --- db.tbl_service_definitions _
                          .Where(Function(x) x.srvc_def_desc = txtSrvDefDesc.Text.Trim()) _
                          .Where(Function(x) txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate >= x.eff_dt And (txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate <= x.end_dt Or x.end_dt = Nullable(of DateTime)).Count()

Answer (score 0):

```
 .Where(Function(x) _
       x.srvc_def_desc = txtSrvDefDesc.Text.Trim() _
       AndAlso txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate >= x.eff_dt _
       AndAlso (Not txtSrvEffDt.HasValue() OrElse txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate <= x.end_dt)).Count()
```

which can be simplified to (if the `Count` is all you're interested in):

```
 .Count(Function(x) _
       x.srvc_def_desc = txtSrvDefDesc.Text.Trim() _
       AndAlso txtSrvEffDt.SelectedDate >= x.eff_dt _
       AndAlso (Not txtSrvEffDt.HasValue() OrElse txtsrvEffDt.SelectedDate <= x.end_dt))
```

Comment: Looking good, but getting "Leading '.' or '!" can only appear inside a 'With' Statement.  I am no VB.NET guru, supporting code.

Comment: Testing.....  Thank...  I am going back and forth from C# to VB.NET Way to much...  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: No prob. Have the same issue myself too. Switching back and forth between the two. And sometimes they mix up. Let me know if it works, then, and please mark as an answer if it does. If not, we'll try again and make it work :)